# Making IFrame persistant with route Reuse and angular

Tags: angular, iframe, angular-routing

I have multiple angular components which all contain a different IFrame. The problem I have is that when I navigate in my application, it triggers a reload of the IFrames. Is there a way to persist the IFrames state when navigating from one page to another. I have tried using the RouteReuseStrategy, but I have not found a way to make it store the IFrame contents. The goal of this is to prevent a reload of the IFrame everytime I navigate back and forth.

Is there a way to do this with a custom route reuse strategy?

Is there any other way to achieve this? Maybe an alternative to IFrames?

Comment: You can not perform any definitive tasks with IFrame but to load and unload them. If you want them to stay while route is changing, then you must place them outside of <router-outlet>

Comment: Any solutions on this issue @Chocoman ???

Comment: I have not found a solution using RouteReuseStrategy. The solution that worked for me was to keep the Iframes ouside the router-outlet and have them loaded all the time but keep them hidden. I then created a service that allows my components to specify which Iframe to show.